# Neo4j Community vs Enterpise Edition in query processing

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I'm asking about differences between both edition of Neo4j: Community and Enterprise if it's any feature which speed up queries like graph traversing in Enterpise Edition?
I'm wondering because while comparing execution query times between Neo4j Community and MySQL, MySQL gave better results, link to discusion:
[Neo4j slower than MySQL in performing recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943800/neo4j-slower-than-mysql-in-performing-recursive-query/41945539#41945539)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j enterprise has currently a few features that make it faster in querying (e.g. a more scalable page-cache and a better lock-manager).

For Neo4j 3.2 a faster Cypher runtime will be available in Neo4j enterprise.

I put also some more feedback / questions into the linked discussion.